# Connection to Neo4j with jdbc No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I am trying to connect to Neo4j with Talend and I get the error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687" in the subject line.  I also get it when I try to connect with a console java application I wrote.  Code below.

I am using a jar file I got from https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/neo4j-jdbc
Is this the most relighable place to get the jar file from or is there a better jar file out there.

The java code on the console application compiles without error so the jar file is not corrupt.

```
/**
* Sample connection to Neo4j using jdbc
* compiled with command javac -cp "neo4j-jdbc-4.0.4.jar" ConnectToNeo4j.java
* executed with command java ConnectToNeo4j
* output 

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
        at ConnectToNeo4j.main(ConnectToNeo4j.java:25)


**/

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.sql.*;
    
    import org.neo4j.jdbc.*;
    import org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jDriver;
    
    class ConnectToNeo4j {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name LIMIT 25";
        try {
    // My passsword isn't passsword !
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "password");
          try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
              while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Found: "+rs.getString("u.name"));
              }
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
          } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
          con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation,

> For the all-in-one module supporting both Bolt and HTTP, you can
> simply use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
    <version>{neo4j-jdbc-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Jar if NOT using Maven:** https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc-driver/4.0.4/neo4j-jdbc-driver-4.0.4.jar

> If you want only one of the protocols, you can depend on its module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>{neo4j-jdbc-version}</version>
</dependency>

or

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-http</artifactId>
    <version>{neo4j-jdbc-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/

Comment: The documentation assumes you are using Maven.  I am not so I am not sure it applies to a console application.  I don't think I need to add in properties for a console application and I have no idea where they would go.

Comment: I gave you a link to the jar file (neo4j-jdbc-driver) in the answer, you need this in order to be able to remove that exception.. @WhoIsKieran

Comment: Downloading the jar file  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc-driver/4.0.4/neo4j-jdbc-driver-4.0.4.jar and putting it into Talend worked.  Thanks.